# Pandas regression with Chunks (big data)

Tags: pandas, chunks

I have a rather large dataset (9GB CSV) and I won't have the memory to analyse this in a full dataframe. Is it possible to perform regression analysis on Chunks of data?

Comment: 9GB of file does not translate to 9GB of memory usage.

Comment: @A.Kot https://stackoverflow.com/q/11715408/9568744

Comment: Also not sure why the downvote. Yes it won’t be 9GB in a dataframe. That will depend on the type of data in the columns. But I may need to add more columns and data into this and the fact remains that it’s a large dataset.

Comment: Do you really need to process all that data?  Can't you take a sample that will fit into memory?

Comment: One of the issues with sampling is that it may end up biasing the variables in some way as I'm not sure it's in a random order (I believe it's time ordered). Is there some way this could be solved?